# Create a home range by CharHull() and with an area less than 100% of the total home range area

Tags: r, geometry, polygon, geospatial, convex-hull

I want to create home ranges by the `CharHull()` function in `adehabitatHR`(`CharHull {adehabitatHR`} - Estimation of the Home Range by Delaunay Triangulation method).

The Description says that I could "select a given percentage of the smallest triangles (measured by their area) as the home-range estimation".
Now I want to select an home range with an area less than 100% of the total CharHull-Area, and finally plotting the contour or converting to a shape-file.
But the command `getverticeshr()` doesn't result in 95 % home range area, it only shows a single small polygon which is a part of the outer polygons of the total home range.

So is there any argument like the "percent= ...." - command in the `mcp()` function? The argument "percent=..." in `plot()` also result in these same single polygons.

I hope, you can help me.

For your information: I have a SpatialPointsDataFrame with one animal but more than 6000 points which I have transformed successfully to CharHull - Polygons, a "MCHu"-class-object but after this the unsolved problem has begun.

And here is an example-data:

```
    library(sp)
    library(rgdal)
    library(adehabitatHR)

### first the data.frame by dput(spdf_proj)
spdf_proj <- 
    structure(list(tag.local.identifier = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "2337", class = "factor"), utm.easting = c(683974.34404956, 
    683974.760661362, 683965.172048386, 683987.281009456, 683985.362453604, 
    683982.219900401, 688531.512618968, 688646.734103846, 688648.699663448, 
    688645.493334214, 688672.516759366, 688647.254958931, 687718.469882875, 
    687720.16874801, 687713.469156302, 687715.945476163, 684638.357135326, 
    682851.713841839, 682477.884670838, 686067.563387058, 682250.807247258, 
    682257.865282583, 681883.067916919, 681785.074428023, 679682.011093641, 
    679683.959645211, 679679.61072749, 679682.334770195, 679682.016356632, 
    681870.417032469, 681833.431666185, 681835.819298651, 682169.045982226, 
    682481.102026817, 681898.903336465, 681815.124474645, 681767.856349565, 
    679683.60677096, 679679.512331425, 679685.090362144, 680056.806449304, 
    680669.183843293, 680574.455914651, 680135.313954264, 679377.580233857, 
    679962.24379583, 681449.590749334, 682487.75669767, 680411.258032117, 
    679696.668518938, 679693.528686564, 679772.603933245, 679773.633868724, 
    679736.151907987, 679052.282925451, 678976.337308103, 679033.29446238, 
    678931.539793955, 678958.703684971, 678946.400181795, 678850.167005458, 
    678773.910379499, 678698.286869888, 678670.305173271, 678919.107223046, 
    678849.346729342, 681189.259381922, 681760.407535151, 681703.846635682, 
    681398.684724269, 681404.573105136, 680342.303016419, 680154.993589284, 
    678462.168244616, 678391.786039819, 676898.732907242, 676001.82835349, 
    678008.813312216, 681769.954749672, 681759.207974324, 681507.518781024, 
    681593.03220131, 681540.302993985, 681484.948396701, 681473.096193411, 
    681472.290180181, 681495.69034936, 681435.364563687, 681447.201456387, 
    681484.561357977, 681486.557645373, 681560.45748688, 681569.439596909, 
    681563.610777719, 681588.547306751, 681569.219963467, 681513.790788761, 
    681152.416214584, 681081.49854309, 681135.953821302), utm.northing = c(5872351.4785664, 
    5872343.56503875, 5872346.22796992, 5872363.42149295, 5872353.8039064, 
    5872349.47411571, 5868340.77361732, 5868243.52829709, 5868235.77558357, 
    5868232.40916611, 5868253.49144986, 5868237.26716877, 5869057.86016266, 
    5869090.09085241, 5869056.34011199, 5869062.72910834, 5870701.37302118, 
    5874368.47157975, 5876177.09623027, 5878230.03361947, 5870680.9824509, 
    5870676.63887016, 5870979.35579, 5871339.76634507, 5873840.86397719, 
    5873841.23739579, 5873841.43141602, 5873842.6355962, 5873844.68392672, 
    5871046.00928802, 5870883.25601619, 5870971.63656481, 5870724.34128791, 
    5870884.41119196, 5871004.71015641, 5870912.68946024, 5871079.80253065, 
    5873839.88786636, 5873837.58571748, 5873842.99459642, 5871951.44683181, 
    5870220.93377831, 5870073.8804179, 5869500.17597069, 5868159.55631067, 
    5867142.10863469, 5870163.2230145, 5871573.15193546, 5873155.16709993, 
    5873906.4137855, 5873904.82657411, 5873914.76176622, 5873923.17474623, 
    5873499.82015583, 5872526.93430836, 5872245.66202465, 5872260.85296241, 
    5869177.40600652, 5869162.02197482, 5869085.16044548, 5868978.3021106, 
    5868905.01581302, 5868857.42295838, 5868902.29988844, 5868275.63384941, 
    5867353.8085983, 5868186.05946818, 5868896.81150499, 5869342.47718761, 
    5869161.06440822, 5868981.86688963, 5867817.37248634, 5867771.05004108, 
    5868056.05939298, 5868402.53585019, 5868159.41355345, 5868319.36565231, 
    5868603.79684903, 5869309.1656903, 5868948.79591208, 5869112.41864817, 
    5869300.35951534, 5869263.37159654, 5869176.9064542, 5869136.82566771, 
    5869116.05926684, 5869101.72778812, 5869055.03378991, 5869106.26144798, 
    5869151.08873567, 5869141.30813259, 5869115.13596271, 5868956.49020514, 
    5868937.08258008, 5869027.92636603, 5869132.38225557, 5869118.44574871, 
    5869157.45021195, 5869112.02210622, 5869153.69116562)), .Names = c("tag.local.identifier", 
    "utm.easting", "utm.northing"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 362243:362342)

### projection
utm32CRS <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84")
coordinates(spdf_proj) <- c("utm.easting", "utm.northing")
proj4string(spdf_proj) <- utm32CRS

### CharHull
spdf_CharHull <- CharHull(spdf_proj)

### Plotting
plot(spdf_CharHull, percent=95)
### -> only one single outer polygon instead of wanted 95 % - area of the total CharHull-Polygons

### getting contours
getverticeshr.MCHu(spdf_CharHull, percent=95)
### same problem as above
```